# Does keybert support French or Spanish text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

https://pypi.org/project/keybert/

```
from keybert import KeyBERT
kw_model = KeyBERT(model='all-mpnet-base-v2')

test_text = """We should save the mother earth so that our future generations can live in a safe environment. We can save the earth by saving trees, natural vegetation, water, natural resources, electricity, etc. We should strictly follow all the possible measures to control the environmental pollution and global warming."""

keywords = kw_model.extract_keywords(test_text,
                                     keyphrase_ngram_range=(3, 3),
                                     stop_words='english',
                                     use_mmr=True,
                                     diversity=0.7)
keywords_list = list(dict(keywords).keys())
print(keywords_list)
```

I have no idea how to get topics from French and Spanish sentences using keybert.

Comment: See: https://github.com/MaartenGr/KeyBERT/issues/24

Answer (score 1):

keyBERT essentially uses sentence transformers at the backend for sentence representation. The following link describes some caveats for using multilingual models.

https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html#multi-lingual-models

The following code snippet is an example of using sentence transformers with keyBERT. `distiluse-base-multilingual-cased-v1` (be aware that this is a cased model) supports 15 languages including french and spannish.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from keybert import KeyBERT
sentence_model = SentenceTransformer("distiluse-base-multilingual-cased-v1")
kw_model = KeyBERT(model=sentence_model)
```

This [tutorial](https://maartengr.github.io/KeyBERT/guides/embeddings.html) describes how embedding models can be used in KeyBERT. Give this a read as well, might help.